# How to control accordions to open only one at a time

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, accordion, html-tag-details

I have multiple accordions. I want to control the `open` state on the `<details>` tag to make sure only one accordion is open at a time. How can I achieve this?

Currently with the code below, the `openState` updates properly, but multiple accordions can be open at the same time (opened accordions does not close when other accordions are opened)

Parent component

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
const openState = ref(Array.from({ length: props.submenu.length }, () => false))

const toggleState = (index: number, newState: boolean) => {
  if (newState)
    openState.value = openState.value.map((_, i) => i === index)
  else
    openState.value[index] = newState
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <template
      v-for="(menu, index) in submenu"
      :key="index"
    >
      <Accordion
        :is-open="openState[index]"
        :name="menu.title"
        @toggle-open-state="(newState) => { toggleState(index, newState) }"
      >
        <template #default>
          content
        </template>
      </Accordion>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Accordion component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
export interface Props {
  isOpen?: boolean
}

const props = defineProps<Props>()

const emits = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'toggle-open-state', isOpen: boolean): void
}>()

const detailsEl = ref()

const isOpen = computed({
  get() {
    return props.isOpen
  },
  set(value) {
    emits('toggle-open-state', value)
    detailsEl.value.open = value
  },
})

const toggleState = () => {
  isOpen.value = !isOpen.value
}
</script>

<template>
  <details
    ref="detailsEl"
    @click="toggleState"
  >
    <summary>
      <p v-html="name"/>
    </summary>
  </details>
</template>
```